# EmguCv : Why I run Yolo with Cuda support on Emgu.Cv 4.5.1 is much slower than CPU

Tags: gpu, emgucv, yolo, darknet

Recently, I am processing image of dimension 96x96 on Emgu.Cv 4.5.1 with Cuda version support, I was trying run on Gpu using:

```
_net.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.Cuda);
_net.SetPreferableTarget(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Target.Cuda);
```

BUT it took 1.2s meanwhile when I ran with:

```
_net.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.OpenCv);
_net.SetPreferableTarget(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Target.Cpu);
```

it only took me 400 ms. My GPU is 1080ti with cuda version 11.2, cudnn 8.0.4.
My questions are:
Does Emgu.cv actually support Gpu when it processes readnet ?
Does anyone run success Yolo on Gpu with emgucv?

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and in my case the first Net.Foward() will take some time. Maybe under the hood is taking some time to initialize or something, but then the next image detections took 3.6ms - 3.7ms.